# Multiple queries into one (Report)?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How do I combine multiple queries into one?

For example:

```
//Successful Sales:
SELECT username, count(*) as TotalSales, sum(point) as Points FROM sales where submit_date >= 1301612400 AND submit_date <= 1304204400 AND status = 1 group by username

/Return Sales:
SELECT username, count(*) as Return FROM sales where submit_date >= 1301612400 AND submit_date <= 1304204400 AND status = 2 group by username

//Unsuccessful Sales:
SELECT username, count(*) as UnsuccessfulSales FROM sales where submit_date >= 1301612400 AND submit_date <= 1304204400  AND (status = 3 OR status = 6) group by username
```

So the report look something like this:
[image]

Also How do I add percentage of return?

Note: Fixed SQL queries

I have tried doing this but couldn't get it to work?

```
SELECT username,  TotalSales, Points, Return
     FROM (
      SELECT username, count(*) as TotalSales, sum(point) as Points FROM sales where submit_date >= 1301612400 AND submit_date <= 1304204400 AND status = 1 group by username
      UNION
      SELECT count(*) as Return FROM sales where submit_date >= 1301612400 AND submit_date <= 1304204400 AND status = 4 group by username
    )
```

..

```
  //  Example Data Structure 

        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sales2` (
          `salesid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
          `point` int(11) NOT NULL,
          `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`salesid`)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

        INSERT INTO `sales2` (`salesid`, `username`, `point`, `status`) VALUES
        (1, 'User1', 2, 1),
        (2, 'User1', 2, 1),
        (3, 'User2', 11, 1),
        (4, 'User2', 1, 2),
        (5, 'User3', 5, 6);
```

field status = 1, successful Sales and show point

status 2 - return sales

status 3/6 - unsuccessful sales:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:
For your first question, I think this will do what you want (but be warned, this query is dog slow, full of table scans... You should ask for a more experienced stack overflow user to optimize that for you):

```
SELECT 
   distinct(outer_sales.username), 
   (SELECT count(*) as Points FROM sales where status = 1 AND username = outer_sales.username) as TotalSales,
   (SELECT sum(point) as Points FROM sales where status = 1 AND username = outer_sales.username) as Points,
   (SELECT count(*) FROM sales where status = 2 AND username = outer_sales.username) as Return,
   (SELECT count(*) FROM sales where (status = 3 OR status = 6) AND username = outer_sales.username) as UnsuccessfulSales
FROM 
   sales outer_sales
ORDER BY
   outer_sales.username;
```

And for the second question, if you just want to add a percent sign to the `Return` column, you can USE the `CONCAT` function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat.

Try:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CAST(COUNT(*) AS CHAR), '%') AS Return ...
```

Comment: Thank you, what about first question. I am stuct with that.

Comment: Could you post your table DDL and some list of insert statements so that I can play around. The query will probably not be that much efficient since I can't think about a way of filtering different status for different fields without resorting to inner queries.

Comment: just updated my question with some list of insert statements and table

Comment: @user622378 updated. And don't forget to add the extra submit_date >= 1301612400 AND submit_date <= 1304204400 to every subquery, I didn't use it because your DDL didn't had it.

Answer (score 1):

If the number (and types) of columns match in the queries, you can use UNION to combine the results of the 3 queries.

Comment: I have tried that, couldnt get it work. Can you show me example please?

Comment: The important thing is that the # of columns match.  You would do something like select col1, col2 from...  UNION select col1, col2  from... UNION select col1, col2 from ...

Comment: This is what I have tried, couldnt get to work: SELECT username,  TotalSales, Points, Return
 FROM (
  SELECT username, count(*) as TotalSales, sum(point) as Points FROM sales where submit_date >= 1301612400 AND submit_date <= 1304204400 AND status = 1 group by username
  UNION
  SELECT count(*) as Return FROM sales where submit_date >= 1301612400 AND submit_date <= 1304204400 AND status = 4 group by username
)

Comment: in your inner query with the UNION you have username, totalsales and points in the first SELECT and just Count() as Return in the second SELECT...the fields in both queries need to be the same:  SELECT username, totalsales, points from table1 UNION SELECT username, totalreturns, points from table2

Comment: @Leslie the point only for status = 1 field. totalsales for status 1. The return field from status = 2

Comment: you are missing the point.  If you are going to have a UNION query then the 2 or more SELECT statements have to have the same number of fields.  Your first SELECT statement has 3 fields returned then you UNION a second SELECT statement that has 1 field returned.  You can change the where clause in each statement but you HAVE to have the same number of fields returned in your SELECT statements.